# SQL Copy data within a table

Tags: sql

I want to make a copy of some of the data in a table, and change only one column. It looks like the following:

```
Before:

C1 C2 C3 ....  // C1 C2 C3 are columns, C3 have same value

a1 b1 c
a2 b2 c
a3 b3 c


After:  

C1 C2 C3 ....  // for the copy, all columns are same except C3, all c and f are same value

a1 b1 c
a2 b2 c
a3 b3 c
...
a1 b1 f
a2 b2 f
a3 b3 f
```

Is there any quick way to do this in sql? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into your_table (C1, C2, C3)
select C1, C2, 'f'
from your_table
```